# cp command based on parent directory

Tags: command-line, zsh, cp, file-copy

I have several folders within a parent folder, which all have the structure below, and am struggling to create a specific loop.

```
parentfolder/folder01/subfolder/map.png
parentfolder/folder02/subfolder/map.png
parentfolder/folder03/subfolder/map.png
parentfolder/folder04/subfolder/map.png
```

etc...

so each subfolder contains a file called `map.png` (i.e. same filename in all subfolders, but they are different files).

I would like to copy each `map.png` file and place it into the overall Parentfolder, but at the same time I want the copy to be renamed based on the Folder above 'subfolder'.

So for example, I want to copy `map.png` from `parentfolder/folder01/subfolder` to parentfolder whilst renaming it `folder01.png` (and for this then to be done accordingly for all others, using a loop).

I have tried something along these lines but am obviously sruggling to get it to do what I want it to:

```bsh
for i in parentfolder/*; do 
  cd $i
  cd subfolder
  cp map.png ../../"$i".png
  cd -
done
```

I am still a beginner and very new to this so would appreciate any help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like the following for loop,

```
for d in parentfolder/* ; do
    cp "$d/subfolder/map.png" "$d.png"
done
```

You should run it when your current directory is on the same level of the `parentfolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Zsh comes with a utility [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) which is good for pattern-based renaming and copying of files. Put this in your `.zshrc` if you don't already have it:

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

(Or run these commands in your shell session to enable them just for this session.)

Then (from `parentfolder`):

```
zcp '(*)/subfolder/map.png' '$1.png'
```

The first argument is the pattern to replace. The second argument is the replacement name. In the replacement, `$1`, `$2` and so on refer to the corresponding parenthesized group in the pattern. See the manual for other possibilities and limitations.